# New Ember project: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance

Tags: ember.js, build, runtime-error

I used the cli to create a new Ember project (v2.18). I'm getting the following error when I try to build/serve the project. This is with 100% clean project, no edits yet. Also fwiw, am using node v14.19.3, npm v6.14.17.

```
  - stack: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1522:5)
at module.exports (/Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/attempt-never-index.js:26:6)
at Builder.build (/Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:156:5)
at BuildTask.run (/Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:29:20)
at /Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:243:46
at tryCatcher (/Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:326:21)
at invokeCallback (/Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:498:33)
at /Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:562:16
at flush (/Users/nikoleizinsli/IdeaProjects/custom-fields-admin/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2441:7)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

UPDATE: I was able to get it to build by using Node v13. We have another Ember 2.18 project that compiles fine on Node v14...so not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're using that version of Ember? It stopped getting updates in 2018. I'd guess this is an issue with Node 14, you may need to go back to Node 10 to get support for ember-cli 2.18. Or, even better, run `npm install -g ember-cli` to get the 4.4 version which supports Node 14+.

Comment: Yeah im restricted to that version because of other software & engines we're working with. I have another ember project thats working fine with the aforementioned node versions, so im not sure thats the issue.